# What is the difference between salesforce.com,salesforce1 and force.com

Tags: community, salesforce1-platform

Some one says salesforce1 is mobile app and salesforce is product.And someone argues salesforce1 is platform.

Can anyone clarify these terms.I am totally confused.

Comment: Sales force is a CRM .... Sales force one is specially built for mobile devices... Force.com is platform where you can do custom development.

Comment: Salesforce1 mobile is now included with the original Salesforce CRM platform. Consequently, Salesforce rebranded the marketing materials for the entire platform as Salesforce1 since all versions of the CRM platform are now mobile by default. Force.com is a different product that doesn't include CRM functionality. You can build apps on it, but you don't get Opportunities and other CRM features like Campaigns, etc.

Comment: Hi   crmprogdev,
What I understood is Salesforce.com is CRM software built on Force.com platform and saleforce1 is the mobile app included to it before.
Now the complete CRM software Salesforce.com is renamed to Salesforce1.Or two seperate CRM softwares released by that vendor with SFDC as without mobile app and Salesforce1 as with mobile app.

Please correct me.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce.com is the Cloud Computing CRM tool which enables you customize, configure according to you business process.It can be B2B and B2C process. All the sales, service and marketing in any business can be implemented using salesforce.com with just some configurations. No special Hardware or sfotware installations are required since it is cloud based all you need is internet connection so that you develop compile on cloud itself.

Salesforce1 is the special version for the mobile devices so that all the users can do any operations from mobile itself.

Force.com is the platform on the salesforce.com which enables you to build applications which are completely new and from scratch using apex and visualforce.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate that You did dare to ask this question. Good question,

Both Salesforce.com and Salesforce1 can be accessed via a web client running on a PC, tablet, or phone.

Salesforce1 is optimized to work on a small touchscreen and can have functions via 3rd party apps to access iOS or Android features like GPS location data.

Also,

Salesforce.com is Sales(CRM) and Service applications which were developed and running on the Force.com Platform. The developed applications will run on the force.com always as a multitenent architecture method. Simply you can identify Force.com is where you can access and customize your datamodel, bussiness logic and UserInterface. But in case of salesforce.com you can access the sales(CRM) Application with all the developed data model, Business logic and UserInterface. Since it is running on the force.com platform, you can customize your application funtionality.

Force.com is based on the concept of Platform as a Service or commonly known as PAAS where as Salesforce.com is based on the concept of Application as a Service. So, we can say Salesforce.com is an application built by Salesforce on force.com platform and has been made available to people for use at per month per license pricing.

And Force.com platform allows you to develope/customize existing or new applications on salesforce.

I hope that this information will help you to unserstand basics of salesforce.

Comment: Thanks for the brief description.
What I understood from this is Salesforce.com is the CRM application built on Force.com platform.
But can you tell whether Salesforce1 is a different version of CRM application like Salesforce.com(SFDC) or just a mobile version of it?

Comment: @user2331760 Nope. Its not different version of CRM. It is purposely developed for Smartphones. So that users can run their business from their smarphones. <br/>

Comment: @user2331760 If my answer is helpful for you, then please upvote it

Comment: Can you please confirm, whether the Salesforce1 is only for smartphones/mobile web version and salesforce.com is for desktop/ full web version.

Comment: Salesforce1 is intended to work on mobile devices. And Yes you can consider a salesforce1 as mobile version of Salesforce.com. Salesforce1, force.com are part of Salesforce.com. Salesforce.com itself is a huge platform on which we can develope applications, showcase our apps, can install and Run apps,can run our business through CRM and also it internet and browser based. So you can consider Salesforce.com as Full Web version.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I think force.com is the base platform for salesforce.com.But you mentioned as force.com is part of salesforce.com.Can you please confirm this one.

Answer (score 0):

salesforce.com is a company and a URL (fact).

Salesforce.com has a CRM product named "Sales Cloud" (fact).  Thus, salesforce.com is NOT a CRM - only Sales Cloud is.

Salesforce1 used to only be the name of the salesforce.com mobile app that accessed their platform.  Given a rebranding, Salesforce1 now referrs to their entire platform, upon which their various products are built (including their Salesforce1 mobile app, Sales Cloud, Service Cloud, etc),

Answer (score 0):

**salesforce.com**

Salesforce.com is the company which provides you to Customize, configure and automate your business process. It works on the concept of Cloud.

Company is listed in New York Stock exchage as ticker name "CRM".[Click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salesforce.com)

**salesforce1**

Salesforce1 is the Mobile App of salesforce.com and enable to access and take action from anywhere. This App can be downloaded for IOS or Android like any other APP. [Click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salesforce.com#Salesforce1)

**force.com**

Force.com is the platform on the salesforce.com which enables you to build applications and it work based on PAAS concept (Platform as a Service). [Click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salesforce.com#Force.com)

***Note:** It started as a CRM tool but now it grew more than that as a platform that can develop as anykid of application from simple website to complex communities or Sales-Service related sites.*